# Can't 'nil' a variable xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Trying to 'nil' some double variables... but getting the 'Assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'void *' error...

This is my properties (trying to make a variable type class, that holds global vars so they can be accessed and changed from anywhere in the app):

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastP;
@property (nonatomic) double brushR;
@property (nonatomic) double brushG;
@property (nonatomic) double brushB;
@property (nonatomic) double brushW;
@property (nonatomic) double brushO;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL mouseSwiped;
```

then I synthesis like so:
    @Synthesis lastP;
    @Synthesis brushR;
    etc, etc,

and when I do a cleanup method (as I'm exiting the view and going back to a menu) and try and nil the vars so they can be deallocated via arc
    brushR = nil;
    brushG = nil;
    lastP = nil;
    etc, etc
I get the error I stated above.

Is it easier to just use [view removefromsuperview] in the parent viewcontroller (as all this information is going into a containerView INSIDE of a view controller (that's the way it needs to be, can't get around this)) and will that kill all the variables from the above calss? or do I need to nil them manually?

if I can just use removefromsuperview (from a parent class) (eg, I have a view controller and then a container view inside that controller, when a button is pushed in the PARENT controller, the app uses [childcontroller removefromsuperview]) will that 'kill' ALL objects being used by the childview (as I have a uiImage inside the childview view and it didn't seem to clear the image it was holding from memory when I tried this method).

if I have to nil my vars (and not just nuke the view and remove it from the hirachy) why isn't it letting me do this?

I really hope I'm understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it easier to just use [view removefromsuperview] in the parent viewcontroller (as all this information is going into a containerView INSIDE of a view controller (that's the way it needs to be, can't get around this)) and will that kill all the variables from the above calss? or do I need to nil them manually?

If you use `ARC`, you don't need to do a cleanup. Runtime will do that for you.

> I have a uiImage inside the childview view and it didn't seem to clear the image it was holding from memory when I tried this method

It will be released as long as there are no other strong references to it.

Comment: thankyou! Sorry guys, thanks for your answers they are a big help (I didn't realise nil only stops the pointer, not releasing the intended reference as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can never nil primitives only pointers. To explain. nil is of type "void *" and you can not assign void * to type float, double etc. you can only assign void * to pointer types. Since a pointer is an address to some memory when you assign nil to the pointer you are pointing the pointer to some memory space that are reserved for nil.

Answer (score 1):

You cann't do this. You can only set `nil` to pointers. Primitives cann't fill with `nil/NULL`. You may assign simple `zero` in these place.

Answer (score 1):

For id type objects you use **nil**. Otherwise for void * (ie a C-style pointer) you can use **NULL**/ **nil**

Use `brushR = 0;` then it should be fine.

Comment: You can only still NULL/nil pointers, not stack allocated primitives/structs.

Answer (score 1):

**Since Double is primitive type ,
therefore ,we cannot set it as nil.
nil or Nil can be set to ObjectType Variable.**